# What does the word "recusus" mean in book titles?

Tags: vocabulary, new-latin

A bit of a mystery here (for someone not very well-versed in Latin at least).

I often encounter the word *recusus* in book titles of the post-classical period, usually but not always in conjunction with *denuo* (anew, again). However, I cannot find the word (or any verb from which it might plausibly be derived) in any of the standard Latin dictionaries that I've consulted.

An example: *Tractatus de morbo mucoso. Denuo recusus annexaque praefatione de trichuridibus novo vermium genere / editus ab Henrico Augusto Wrisberg.*

Another: *I. Bodini Methodus Ad Facilem Historiarum Cognitionem: Accurate Denuo Recusus; Subiecto Rerum Indice.*

I have a hunch that it means something like "corrected" or "edited". Am I right?

Comment: The word is present in Whitaker's Words without any problem... Not with the "print" translation, but it is there. http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=recusus

Answer (score 8):

According to [Johann Ramminger's](http://nlw.renaessancestudier.org/biblio_lrz/biblio.htm) [Neo-Latin Word List](http://nlw.renaessancestudier.org/neulateinische_wortliste.htm), *recudere* [means](http://www.neulatein.de/words/0/001916.htm) "to print" or "to reprint."

It is doubtlessly derived from classical *cudere* "to strike, to stamp or coin money."

Thus, *denuo recusus* means "newly printed."

Comment: Just barely beat me!

Comment: @cmw Numquam mihi in mentem venit ut te cudam 

Comment: What's the Latin for "good play on words"?

Answer (score 5):

It's [Neo-Latin](https://neolatinlexicon.org/adumbratio-old/), the perfect passive participle of *recudere*, which itself likely was coined on *cudere*, and it means "printed" or "reprinted."

So sometimes you'll see *accurate denuo recusus*, which means "accurately printed again."

Cudo, cudere:

> II. Transf. (of metals), to prepare by beating or hammering, to forge; of money, to stamp, coin: “plumbeos nummos,” Plaut. Most. 4, 2, 11: “argentum,” Ter. Heaut. 4, 4, 18: “anulum,” to make, Quint. 9, 2, 61.— *
> B. Trop.: “quas tu mihi tenebras cudis?” forge, prepare, Plaut. Ep. 3, 4, 40.

I imagine the word was developed on analogy with coins.

Comment: Thanks for this!